# Table and buttons in html and php with bootstrap

Tags: php, html

In this code that have to print a table and 3 buttons, the 3 buttons appear above the table but i want them under the table. What can I fix? 
And how can i print them inline? I tried with a div with style display inline but doesn't work.

```
echo "<div class='container'>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<table class='table table-hover' style='border: 1px solid black; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;'><caption><h2>Esperienze di Lavoro</h2>
</caption> <thead> <tr>";
    echo "<th style='border: 1px solid black;'> Username </th><th style='border: 1px solid black;'> Password </th><th style='border: 1px solid black;'> Nome </th> <th style='border: 1px solid black;'> Cognome </th> <th style='border: 1px solid black;'> Data di Nascita </th> <th style='border: 1px solid black;'> Email </th> <th style='border: 1px solid black;'> Foto </th>";
    echo "</tr> </thead> <tbody> <tr>";
    echo "<td style='border: 1px solid black;'>".$_COOKIE["username"]."</td>";
    echo "<td style='border: 1px solid black;'>".$_COOKIE["password"]."</td>";
    echo "<td style='border: 1px solid black;'>".$_COOKIE["name"]."</td>";
    echo "<td style='border: 1px solid black;'>".$_COOKIE["surname"]."</td>";
    echo "<td style='border: 1px solid black;'>".$_COOKIE["birth"]."</td>";
    echo "<td style='border: 1px solid black;'>".$_COOKIE["mail"]."</td>";
    echo "<td style='border: 1px solid black;'><img src=".$_COOKIE["foto"]." style='width:128px;height:128px;'></td>";
    echo "</tr></tbody</table>";
    echo "
    <div class='form-group'>        
  <div class='col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10'><button type='button' name='mod_nome' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='Funzione1()';>Modifica Informazioni</button></div>
</div>";
    echo "<div class='form-group'>        
  <div class='col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10'><button type='button' name='studio' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='Funzione2()';>Aggiungi Esperienze </button></div>
</div>";
    echo "
<div class='form-group'>        
  <div class='col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10'> <button type='button' name='comp' onclick='Funzione7()' class='btn btn-primary';>Compagnie in cui i nostri iscritti lavorano</button></div>
</div>";
```

I'm using bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

Your button code is fine, you just need to close `<tbody></tbody>`

```
echo "</tr></tbody></table>";
```

To align the buttons,

```
<style>
#btnSearch,
#btnClear{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
</style>       
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
        <button id="btnSearch" class="btn btn-primary btn-md center-block" Style="width: 100px;">button-1</button>
         <button id="btnClear" class="btn btn-danger btn-md center-block" Style="width: 100px;">button-2</button>
         <button id="btnClear" class="btn btn-danger btn-md center-block" Style="width: 100px;">button-3</button>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok perfect and for the second question?